# Add elements in ArrayList in more readable way

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have below code snippet to add the elements in `ArrayList`

```
List <Integer> myList = new  ArrayList();
myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
myList.add(3);
myList.add(4);
```

I am looking for more readable and elegant way to add the elements in `ArrayList`, something like below. I know below is not allowed but is there any other readable/elegant way?

```
myList.add(1).add(2).add(3).add(4)
```

**UPDATE:-** i am on java 1.6

Comment: I would still stick to the first and not so elegant solution. Maybe it's not significant in terms of performance at first look, but there's always a little bit of trade off coming with the solutions presented below. Either creating additional objects or creating new classes which aren't really needed in your application, or even importing new dependencies, and there has to be always a very good reason for that, and in most cases this is not a good enough reason.

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth: In your bio you say: you are _looking to improve_. Improving would be to leverage the API and use one of the proposed answers. All 4 of the current posted answers are better than the first solution ;)

Comment: @jlordo: To be perfectly honest I've already used most of the suggested solutions before and I still use some of them but improving doesn't always mean inventing or introducing new but sometimes to stick with the simplest possible way. And I don't say those solutions are not valid (I clicked upvote for a reason ;)), I simply wanted to give another point of view.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you know the elements prior to instantiating:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

or if you want to add them to an existing list:

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
// do stuff
myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

To make it more readable, you can

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
```

and simply use

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

or

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
// do stuff
myList.addAll(asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

---

In case you know that you never ever want to add more elements to the list, you can simply write

```
List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

or with the static import:

```
List<Integer> myList = asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: @Anirudh it is very elegant though.

Comment: Did you mean:List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4); ?

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth: No, because he couldn't add any more elements to that list in the future.

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth: Edited my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

[Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) way(though List is immutable):

```
ImmutableList<Integer> myList = ImmutableList.<Integer>builder()
                             .add(1)
                             .add(2)
                             .add(3)
                             .build();
```

or this way:

```
List <Integer> myList = Lists.newArrayList(1,2,3);
```

or

```
List <Integer> myList = Ints.asList(1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you find this readable, here's one more way

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(1);add(2);add(3);
}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can chain method by extending `ArrayList`..Then you add a method `addMe` that would return the new `ArrayList` class

```
class chainedArrayList extends ArrayList
{
     public chainedArrayList addMe(Object o)
     {add(o);return this;}
}
```

You can now chain the methods

```
mychainedArrayList.addMe(1).addMe(2).addMe(3).addMe(4);
```

Comment: I think if you were considering creating a whole new class, you'd be better off just writing a helper method that takes in n parameters and adds them to the list.

Comment: @Supericy yes you are right..unless he doesn't want some extra efforts to prevail over readability

Answer (score 1):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections), you can use the following if you want a mutable List of Integer:

```
MutableList<Integer> list1 = Lists.mutable.with(1).with(2).with(3).with(4);
MutableList<Integer> list2 = Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4);
Assert.assertEquals(list1, list2);
```

If you would like a mutable list of int, without boxing, you can use the following:

```
MutableIntList primitiveList1 = IntLists.mutable.with(1).with(2).with(3).with(4);
MutableIntList primitiveList2 = IntLists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4);
Assert.assertEquals(primitiveList1, primitiveList2);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. But I guess the value is not allways 1...4. Still you culd possibly use a for loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i ++){
mylistAdd(i)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately because it returns boolean you can do it in the style of a builder unless you extend it.

Have a look to see if the [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Lists) (Google collections) have anything that suits you. They use builder style that may or may not suit you. Like..

```
public static <E> List<E> asList(@Nullable 
             E first,
             E[] rest)
```

You could also look at using [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections) if you want a shortened version in Java

```
def list = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

But to be honest doing a for loop and an add is elegant enough and there are more things to worry about than this.

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is Arrays.asList(T...) as stated above. But here is another way to do it:

```
public class CollectionChain<T, C extends Collection<T>> {

    public static <T> CollectionChain<T, ArrayList<T>> newArrayList(T inital) {
        return start(new ArrayList<>(), inital);
    }

    public static <T, C extends Collection<T>> CollectionChain<T, C> start(C collection, T inital) {
        return new CollectionChain<>(collection).add(inital);
    }

    private final C collection;

    private CollectionChain(C collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public CollectionChain<T, C> add(T value) {
        collection.add(value);
        return this;
    }

    public final CollectionChain<T, C> addAll(T... values) {
        return addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
    }

    public CollectionChain<T, C> addAll(Collection<T> values) {
        collection.addAll(values);
        return this;
    }

    // Add other chained actions

    public C get() {
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
import static project.path.CollectionChain.*;

List<String> chainResult = newArrayList("Needed to properly resolve the type").add("A test").addAll("1", "2").get();
```

This way only one List will be created and filled.